# How can I tell if my presta valves have removable cores?

Tags: presta, sealant

I read about valves that have removable cores and that is better for applying sealant. How can I tell if my valves have cores that are removable?  (I don't have the type of the tube, or any other info; used bike).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a close look.

On a presta valve there is a wide threaded part that the lock ring attaches to. And a narrower part with the valve lock nut above it that the cap threads onto.

If the narrow part has two flat sides to get a tool onto, then it's removable.

Comment: Most on sale aren't removable.